# Dell Inspiron 1120 Ubuntu Light -> Desktop and now I'm having problems with wifi and suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend-resume, ubuntu-light

I got a Dell Inspiron 1120 which ships with Ubuntu Light, as well as Windows.  My wife prefers Ubuntu, but obviously outside of web stuff, you can't do a lot with Light, so I went ahead and installed the Desktop version of Ubuntu (10.10 / maverick).

Whereas before it suspended beautifully and connected to wifi networks flawlessly, it now displays the following problems:

- It seems to suspend ok, but on resume, the screen remains blank, even though the computer appears to wake up again.
- Wifi doesn't connect.

I tried using the suggested proprietary drivers, and those don't seem to change the situation.

All in all, a bit frustrating to run into these sorts of "regressions" - does anyone know what sort of drivers and such Ubuntu Light might have shipped with for this computer that made it work so well?  Unfortunately, I wiped the disk in order to install the Desktop version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Ubuntu Image from Dell, maybe that will help:
http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=de&l=de&s=gen&releaseid=R281810&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=416533

And some more tools: http://search.euro.dell.com/results.aspx?s=gen&c=de&l=de&cs=&k=ubuntu+light&cat=all&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 1):

My WiFi problem is solved by installing `broadcom-sta-common` (on 12.04.2 LTS), then restart:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install broadcom-sta-common
sudo reboot
```

My device is:

*$ lspci | grep BCM*

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```