# Dell Inspiron 1120 Wifi, Bluetooth problems

Tags: 12.04, networking, dell, bluetooth, inspiron

([A related question found here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27728))

I've been used 11.04, now 12.04 LTS, and if there is solution, I don't want to upgrade from that LTS.

The first problem is, that the **network-manager/networking** behaves wrong:

- when I'm on battery, the WiFi connects (the mobile broadband also), but no network can be accessed, like when something timing out. If I connect the AC charger, it immediately starts working.
- usually just lists the options: enable network, enable wireless network, enable mobile broadband, edit networks & network information, there are no lists of available networks, etc...

**Bluetooth**:

- The Bluetooth is always turns on on start up, but when I turn it off on another 12.04 LTS, it remembers, and doesn't turn on on start up.

Conclusion: this laptop is no longer mobile, it requires AC charger to connect to networks.

---

### What I have tried to solve the main problem?

- Upgrade the network-manager, to the latest [daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~network-manager/+archive/trunk) version: 0.9.6.0~git201208071622.5714-0~pkg562~precise1
- replace wireless driver with b43, but is was not supported ([How do I get a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127633))
- upgrade the BIOS. Now I have version A05, the latest is A06, but I couldn't because I haven't found the HDR file [in Dell's repos](http://linux.dell.com/repo/firmware/bios-hdrs/) (there is no *system_bios_ven_0x1028_dev_0x0470_version_A06* dir), and I could't generate if from the Windows executable (wine /writehdrfile /nopause now doesn't work) - [original tutorial is here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Dell_BIOS_Upgrade)
- install some Dell software/firmware:

```
ii  dell-dup                                      1.1.3-0ubuntu2                                        A firmware-tools plugin for Dell DUP images
ii  firmware-addon-dell                           2.2.9-0ubuntu1                                        A firmware-tools plugin to handle BIOS/Firmware for Dell systems
```

---

### Information:

- `sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 5c:26:0a:46:bd:49
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:d0200000-d023ffff ioport:a000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 88:25:2c:e4:55:83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 ip=172.27.1.13 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d0300000-d0303fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wwan0
       serial: 02:80:37:ec:02:00
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=Mobile Broadband Network Device link=no multicast=yes
```

- `sudo lspci -vnn -d 14e4:`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d0300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] #14e4
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

- `sudo smbios-sys-info`

```
Libsmbios version:      2.2.28
Product Name:           Inspiron 1120
Vendor:                 Dell Inc.
BIOS Version:           A05
System ID:              0x0470
```

- `lcpci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Dell Device 9602
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series]
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

- `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
dm_crypt               23125  1 
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224173  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  4 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17764  1 snd_hda_codec
dell_wmi               12681  0 
snd_pcm                97275  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
dell_laptop            18119  0 
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
dcdbas                 14490  1 dell_laptop
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
fglrx                3264017  69 
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
ums_realtek            18248  0 
cdc_ether              13536  0 
usbnet                 26212  1 cdc_ether
psmouse                97485  0 
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
snd                    79041  18 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
uas                    18180  0 
cdc_wdm                17581  0 
cdc_acm                26821  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
edac_core              53746  0 
soundcore              15091  1 snd
sp5100_tco             13791  0 
k10temp                13166  0 
edac_mce_amd           23709  0 
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
i2c_piix4              13301  0 
btusb                  18332  1 
shpchp                 37277  0 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180153  13 btusb,rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
mac_hid                13253  0 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17390  0 
wl                   2568249  0 
lib80211               14381  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
vesafb                 13844  1 
usb_storage            49198  1 ums_realtek
wmi                    19256  1 dell_wmi
video                  19596  0 
atl1c                  41718  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiFi problem:

> - when I'm on battery, the WiFi connects (the mobile broadband also),    but no network can be accessed, like when something timing out. If I
>     connect the AC charger, it immediately starts working.

is solved by installing `broadcom-sta-common` (on 12.04.2 LTS), then restart:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install broadcom-sta-common
sudo reboot
```

My device is:

*$ lspci | grep BCM*

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

---

The network manager pop-up problem is still exists, tried with the current stable and the testing releases [from that PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mathieu-tl/+archive/nm) with no success...